# Is there any guarantee for the order in which C++ stack variables are destroyed

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
{
  std::auto_ptr<Something> p1(pSomePointer);
  std::auto_ptr<Something> p2(pSomeOtherPointer);
  ...
}
```

Is there any guarantee that p2 destructor will be called before p1's when exiting the scope? Common sense says that the stack variables should be destroyed from top of the stack first but C++ compiler can reorder assignments.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they are destroyed in order opposite to the construction order - objects constructed last will be destroyed first. C++ guarantees this.

Comment: ...and not only for stack variables.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, and the latter can lead to all sorts of bugs if care is not taken.

Comment: @sbi what other variables are we talking about? Global?

Comment: @Elemental: Global variable order of destruction is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Elemental: Yes, globals and (namespace-scope or class-scope) statics.